# How to build a mobile card URL in Salesforce1?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, urlhacking

I'd like to be able to navigate in Salesforce1 directly to a mobile card (a Visualforce page in this case).  The layout for the custom object in question is large and it seems like a waste of time to load it if everything mobile users need is on the mobile card.

Nothing in the sforce.one navigation object looks like it provides that capability.  Details [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm).

The URL for the mobile card is ugly.  In fact, mine is over 800 characters long (the part after "https://cs13.salesforce.com/one/one.app#").  Looking at it, I thought there's no way that's any kind of ID; it must be encoded data. But encoded how?  The string had only alphanumeric characters, so I tried a base64 decoder on a hunch.

Here's what I got:

```
{"componentDef":"one:alohaPage","attributes":
{"values":
{"address":"/apex/SimpleSiteProgram?id=a0ZW0000000Rs8tMAC",
"history":["<Another Base64 string trimmed for space considerations>"]}},"t":1410988803034}
```

SimpleSiteProgram is my mobile card (Visualforce page).  The ID is the Salesforce ID of the record I was looking at.  It seems possible that I could have a button in  a VF page that would build a Salesforce1-appropriate URL.

Is this possible?  Are there reasons I shouldn't do it even if it might work for now?  And does anyone have ideas on what "t" and the number following it mean?

**edited to add**
The number after the "t" in the last line of the decoded URL comes up different if I try this for another object's mobile card.  In fact, it comes up different if I navigate away from the mobile card and come back.  The higher-order digits are the same.  It might be counting something (api calls, pages views, something else?).

Comment: `t` is most likely a timestamp